# Javascript getting element carret is in returns wrong element

Tags: javascript, html, element

I am trying to get the element (usually a span) a user is typing in javascript. That works fine on every keystroke:

```
textArea.onkeyup = function(event){
  var sel = window.getSelection(); //Not working yet!
  if(typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"){
    if(sel.isCollapsed && sel.rangeCount > 0){
      var node = null;
      node = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
      node = ((node.nodeType === 1) ? node : node.parentNode);
      alert(node);
    }  
  }
}
```

But when I use the arrow keys to move left and right, it starts to return **G** all the time.

I am using a contenteditable div and would be happy if someone can help me out!

Thanks, Lucas

Comment: will focus() method help? Can you please create a jsfiddle

Comment: Focus is not working and unfortunately, a jsfiddle would be very complex to read due to the large amount of code.

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve)

Comment: I created for you bin - http://jsbin.com/qevumo/edit?html,js,output. I don't understand the problem.